# How to recompile and launch Java FX application with Maven and Intell IJ idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

In tutorial for Java FX application with Maven, only following code was in `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example_artefact_id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

If to run `Run Maven build` in IntelliJ IDEA, it will finish with `BUILD SUCCESS` message. First what I did not understand: what is next? No app that could be started.

I found some info that it's required to create the `jar` by the following plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>jp.co.yd.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Is far as I understand, after editing code it's require to recompile app, create new jar and start it. How I should to setup IntelliJ IDEA to do above action at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a maven project , so to create the jar you only need to put

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

execute

`mvn clean install`

and you'll find the `.jar` in the Target File

you can after that use this jar to run your javaFx jar using :

```
java -jar jarName.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but can I do this two action `mvn clean install` and `java -jar jarName.jar` at once (by one button or shortcut)? No way IDEA do not provide this capability...

Comment: create a file with name scrip.sh , put in this file the two commands , save and after execute it by `./script.sh` in linux (on windows you can use .bat instead of .sh)

Comment: you can also try use `mvn clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=yourMainClassWithPackage`